# IP CCTV camera Failing upload of captured images after router change

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip-camera

I have an IP CCTV camera that is triggered by motion. Before upgrading my router it would capture images successfully and upload them to a webserver.

However, after upgrading my home router to a Netgear R7000P AC2300 Nighthawk I have noticed a number of images fail to upload to the server correctly. They basically do not upload completely.

Is there anything to look for with my router configuration that could help aid in diagnosing what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the server is on the same network as the ip cameras (LAN) then make sure your router allows LAN file sharing. Make sure your server is connected properly to the new router. (Also make sure your ip cameras are connected properly). A big possibility is that you forgot to edit the ip address that the ip cameras connect to upload their footage, since every device has a new local ip on each network.

Comment: The server is a remote web box I have. The camera writes to it using FTP. I can access the IP Cameras with the mobile app when connected to the local network and outside of the network.

Comment: can you access the ftp server from your phone?

Comment: Yup and via the computer as well

Comment: Can you confirm that the ip cameras are properly connected to the new internet connection.

Comment: Yeah they are, say out of every 10 pictures, only 5 go up to the FTP server. But, this number is not consistent, sometimes they will all upload other times only 1 or 2 upload. Any thoughts could the camera be being tunnelled via UDP instead of TCP now for some reason?